# What is a good convention for table key id name?

Tags: relational-database, keys

I'm wondering if there is any good convention for key attributes in relational datatables.

- ID or Id seems to be good. however it conflict with others ids when joining.
- MyTableNameId does not conflicts when joining, however your software must know the ID name for each table.

There is any good practice?

Comment: When joining, you should be explicitly specifying the tables anyway.  Any database worth its salt will squawk about ambiguous queries.

Comment: +1 for Blrfl's comment.  Don't prefix columns with the table name.  `select t1.item, t2.anotheritem from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.foreignkeycolumn` is no harder to write or understand than something like `select table1_item, table2_anotheritem from table1 left join table2 on table1_id = table2_foreignkeycolumn`, and having the prefix makes it harder to read when you *aren't* writing a join..

Answer (score 7):

With `id` vs `table_id`, its six of one, half dozen of the other.  In either case its the same number of characters in a query (user_id vs user.id).  And instead of conflicts on 'id', you have potential conflicts on the joined columns if other tables are referencing it.

Personally, I use `id` as a matter of course, even if I may not need an auto incrementing id.  My recommendation is to pick one and be consistent. What you don't want is some tables with `id` and others with `table_id`.

Answer (score 3):

What I've seen in those databases that use surrogates for everything is as follows:

```
    - person_id
    - account_id
    - event_id
    ...etc
```

Regarding your statement:

> ...however your software must know the ID name for each table.

It makes me think you are using some OR mapping framework in which case you should follow the recommendations from that framework. Or maybe you are using a RAD tool that would create the tables, forms and queries for you, in which case you should abide to what the tool gives you.

If you are modeling the database yourself and writing queries yourself, the `_id` suffix is very common.

EDIT: [PPDM](https://www.ppdm.org)'s [Architechtural Principles](https://wiki.ppdm.org/index.php?title=Architectural_Principles) document also give `_no` as an alternative suffix (abbreviation for number), giving `account_no`, `observation_no`, `sequence_no` etc:

> ...surrogate key components such as _ID, OBS_NO or SEQ_NO may be added
>   as a component of the Primary key.

Comment: I prefer Id prefix, not suffix, for both primary and foreign keys. That way when I am writing a query in a software like Navicat, I can start typing Id on join and immeditately get the list of the Ids that are referenced.

Comment: @DavidPacker That's very uncommon and not widely accepted, though. Besides, typing the alias of the table followed by a dot should get you the list of columns in order of creation, meaning the id would be usually first.

Comment: Foreign keys do not come as first.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I prefer using 'key' for the (surrogate) primary key of a table.  This is a bit heretical so I normally conform to whatever other people expect.  The issue of the field names colliding is only true if you are not qualifying the fields in the query.  I think that's bad practice for outside of ad-hoc queries.  For example, Lets say I have two (normalized) tables:

```
Organization    Person
------------    ------------
key             key
name            firstname
                lastname
                organization
```

A query might look like this:

```
select per.key, per.firstname, per.lastname
  from Person per
  join Organization org
    on org.key = per.organization
 where org.name = :org_name
```

I prefer this because I don't have to think about what the name of the key column of the table is (it's always 'key') and to my eye, the join clause is tells you exactly what you are doing.  Of course it is heresy to name things in a clear concise way in a DB so you may be crucifed for doing such a thing.  I therefore cannot recommend this without some reservation.  If there's a standard already in place, you should probably just follow that.  Generally, it's easier to work with a poor but uniform naming approach than a patchwork of naming approaches even when some are really good.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to prefix my foreign keys with the table name (in singular form), and export them without further prefixing them. This makes it clear you are joining on the proper column.

```
SELECT c.name,
       o.date,
       o.total_amount
FROM   orders AS o JOIN customers c
ON     o.customer_id = c.customer_id
```

As compared to:

```
SELECT c.name,
       o.date,
       o.total_amount
FROM   orders AS o JOIN customers c
ON     o.id = c.id
```

This may be a little more difficult if your are using natural keys.